# How do I use the free() function in c?

Tags: c, memory, error-handling, free

I'm using this function in my program:

```
static void free_envp(char **envp)
{
    free(envp);
}
```

I can't figure out how I should manage errors and which errors can occur, neither online nor in the man page.

Does anyone know what I should be aware of using it?

Comment: *How* are you "using this function"? *What* errors do you need to "manage"? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The only error you can get with `free` is _undefined behaviour_ (google that) if the argument you provide to `free` is something else than a pointer that has previously been returned by `malloc` and friends or if that pointer has already been freed previously. The only way to "manage" these errors is using `free`correctly. BTW it is OK to call `free` upon a `NULL` pointer; it won't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

The `free` function is called to free the memory which has been allocated on the heap. i.e. via `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

You should pass the same pointer that was returned by `malloc` to the `free` function. Since `NULL` can be returned by `malloc` in some cases, it is safe to pass `NULL` as argument to `free`, so that `free(NULL)` just does nothing.

Also, you should call the `free` function only once per `malloc`. Calling `free` on a pointer which has not been allocated or has already been freed is undefined behaviour.

For this reason, could be a good idea to set a pointer to `NULL` after is has been freed, if you are going to use it again.

```
int *p;
p = malloc(n * sizeof(int));  // n is size of the array
if (p == NULL)
{
    // Take appropriate action, e.g. exit the program.
}
....
.....

// After all use of the memory is over, if allocated properly before.
free(p);
p = NULL;
```

Comment: If the function failed to allocate the requested block of memory using **malloc** function, a null pointer is returned. So after allocation of memory, whether the **p** pointer is NULL or not. if **p** is not a NULL pointer, we can the free the memory using **free(p)**. otherwise it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: @EswaranPandi your comment is somewhat confusing (did you forget some words?). But calling `free` upon a `NULL` pointer is OK.

Answer (score 1):

The `envp` argument sounds like the environment pointer that is part of the `main` definition:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]);
```

Just as `argv`, you *cannot* deallocate `envp`. It is passed by the process environment.

<sub>(If your `envp` parameter has nothing to do with the `envp` argument of `main`, then you can ignore this part of my answer).</sub>

Note: you pass your function a pointer-to-a-pointer and then deallocate that. But probably the target of the pointer should be deallocated:

```
static void free_envp(char **envp)
{
    free(*envp);  // note the '*'
}
```